# How to pass props to a component passed as a prop?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm building a little React Native app and am using react-native-route-flux (v3). I'm having trouble passing down props based on the parent's state to components rendered inside the Scene.

Here is the relevant code:

```
render() {

let {
  drawerOpen
} = this.state

return (
    <Router>
      <Scene
        style={styles.app}
        key='root'>
          <Scene
            passProps={true}
            key='Home'
            component={MainView}
            title='Home'
            initial={true}
            hideNavBar={true}
            customNavBar={<AppHeader handleDrawer={() => this._handleDrawer()} />}
            drawer={<Drawer open={drawerOpen} />} />
          <Scene
            key='Tutorial'
            component={TutorialTile}
            title='Tutorial'
            hideNavBar={true}
            customNavBar={<AppHeader handleDrawer={() => this._handleDrawer()} />}
            drawer={<Drawer open={drawerOpen} />} />
      </Scene>
    </Router>

)

}
```

However, the `open` prop of the `<Drawer />` component never gets updated on parent state change and therefore never opens.

Is there a way to pass down props to components that are themselves passed down as props? (the router library pretty much requires me to pass the Drawer down as a prop).

Thank you!

edit: here is the `_handleDrawer` function which is passed down to a button in the header:

```
_handleDrawer() {

let { drawerOpen } = this.state

this.setState({
  drawerOpen: !drawerOpen
})

}
```

Comment: What does your _handleDrawer() function?

Comment: edited my questuon to provide the function